# How to pass a prototype function name to another prototype function

Tags: javascript

```
function car() {
}

car.prototype = {
 update1: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update1")
 },
 update2: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update2")
 },
 update3: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update3")
 },
 update: function(s, updateFn) {
   this.updateFn.call(this, s)
 }
}

var c = new car()

c.update("tyres", 'update1')
```

I want to pass a function name (update1 or update2 or update3) to update function

output should be : `updated tyres with update1;`

Comment: You can't have multiple `update1` properties in the same object.

Comment: `this[updateFn].call(this, s)`

Comment: sorry, copy paste mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x8jwavje/

```
 function car() {
    }

car.prototype = {

 update1: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update1")
 },
 update2: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update1")
 },
 update3: function(s) {
   console.log("updated "+s+" with update1")
 },
 update: function(s, updateFn) {

   this[updateFn]( s)
 }
}

var c = new car()

c.update("tyres", 'update1')
```

this is how you should call a function whose name passed as a parameter `this[updateFn]( s)`

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/x8jwavje/1/